# How to see output in tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am running tomcat in windows and I want to see the output files of the Java programs and that of jsp files I ran using tomcat.The problem is that my tomcat log directory doesn't have any `stdout` or `stderr` file. What to do?

These are all the files that I have in log:

```
catalina.log
host-manager.log
localhost.log
localhost_access.log
manager.log
```

Comment: if you are running from eclispe, you will get it in the console view. Window -> show view -> console

Comment: No I am running it manually..What should I do?

Comment: how you start server? `catalina start` ?

Comment: by clicking on startup.bat

Answer (score 2):

By default, Tomcat stores its log files in `<tomcat-dir>/logs/`. Look at `catalina.out`.

Comment: Did you change any config files? Are you sure Tomcat's even starting?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the output by going to `startup.bat` process window. The output will be shown there